# How modify this function, that it will detect the visibile buffers in all windows?

Tags: buffers, window, kill-buffer

I found a function, that will kill all buffers except the current buffer that's open.

```
(defun kill-other-buffers () 
  "Kill all buffers but the current one.
Doesn't mess with special buffers."
  (interactive)
  (when (y-or-n-p "Are you sure you want to kill all buffers but the current one? ")
    (seq-each
     #'kill-buffer
     (delete (current-buffer) (seq-filter #'buffer-file-name (buffer-list))))))
```

It works great. However, when I have two windows open with a different buffer in each window, I noticed it kills the visible buffer in the other window too, except for the buffer where the cursor currently in is.

I studied the manuals of Emacs, in order to detect the open buffers that are visible  in all windows. But I found not one. So I'm wondering if anyone have a good suggestion for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the `window-list` of each frame in `frame-list`.

Rather than:

```el
(delete (current-buffer) 
        (seq-filter #'buffer-file-name (buffer-list)))
```

You could use:

```el
(let (buflist)
  (dolist (frame (frame-list))
    (dolist (window (window-list frame t))
      (push (window-buffer window) buflist)))
  (seq-filter (lambda (buf)
                (and (buffer-file-name buf)
                     (not (memq buf buflist))))
              (buffer-list)))
```

You could simplify that slightly using `walk-windows` which accepts an ALL-FRAMES parameter:

```el
(let (buflist)
  (walk-windows (lambda (window)
                  (push (window-buffer window) buflist))
                t t)
  (seq-filter (lambda (buf)
                (and (buffer-file-name buf)
                     (not (memq buf buflist))))
              (buffer-list)))
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but when I add your first suggestion and then the second suggestion. They also kill the visible buffers in the other windows. So I wondered if you tried the function `kill-other-buffers` itself with the `buflist` modification?

Comment: Each of my suggestions produces the list of buffers to kill (if substituted into your original code). You can trivially test each suggestion with `M-:` and confirm whether the resulting list includes any of the visible buffers. I've just tested your `kill-other-buffers` function with one of my alternatives, and for me it's working as I expected.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read your message thoroughly. I evalated your modification for buffer outside the function `kill-other-buffers` instead inside the function, replacing the `(delete [..] )`. 
It works greatly, thanks for that.

Comment: One question, I wondered how I could kill with the same function special buffers like Buffer list as well? I noticed they don't get killed (Buffer list, Magit status window, helm, etc).

Comment: n.b. That behaviour is based on your original code, which filters the list of candidates to only those which are visiting a file -- for which `(buffer-file-name BUFFER)` returns non-`nil`.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could interpret your comment, in order to modify my own Elisp code. Do you mean I need to find a way to add special buffers like `*Messages*` buffer which are opened but hidden, to the `buflist` list?

Comment: You can modify the logic in my versions however you wish. If you replaced `(buffer-file-name buf)` with something like `(or (buffer-file-name buf) (derived-mode-p 'magit-mode 'tabulated-list-mode 'special-mode 'dired-mode))` then it would additionally kill (non-visible) buffers using those major modes (or derivatives thereof). You might also (or alternatively) test `(buffer-name buf)` against particular names. Whatever you need. An `or` form can have any number of arguments, so you can encapsulate all the tests you need within that form.

Comment: If you don't want *any* constraints on what you kill, other than the visibility in a window, then you would reduce `(and (buffer-file-name buf) (not (memq buf buflist)))` to simply `(not (memq buf buflist))`, but you possibly don't want to do that.

Comment: Thank you phils. Even I'm not able to understand it, it's really appreciated!